# initialization of variables in drools drl fails

Tags: variables, drools

I'm trying to use initialization of variables in my rules.
Though the following simplified drl is not working because the "init" rule is executed after the "has computer" rule.

```
package org.drools
import example.brms.Dossier;

global example.brms.Session session;
global java.lang.String TCOMPUTER;

rule "init"
salience 10000
when
then
    session.set("TCOMPUTER", "440949");
    System.out.println("all set!");
end

rule "has computer"
when
    $dossier : Dossier( objects.group("T3").type(TCOMPUTER).exists() )
then
    session.info("GOT-COMPUTER", $dossier, TCOMPUTER.getClass());
end
```

session.set("TCOMPUTER", "440949"); calls ksession.setGobal(...) internally.

I insert 2 Dossier facts and fire the rules:

```
log.debug("Inserting " + facts.size() + " facts");
for (Object fact : facts) {
    ksession.insert(fact);
}

/** GO! **/
log.debug("ksession.fireAllRules()");
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

I get this in the console:

```
Starting Engine in PHREAK mode
Inserting 2 facts

Reducing to types null  <-- why these to lines before fireAllRules ?
Reducing to types null  <-/

ksession.fireAllRules()
Setting ksession global TCOMPUTER to 440949
all set!
```

The type() method of Dossier( objects.group("T3").**type**(TCOMPUTER).exists() ) prints the "Reducing to types null".

So it seems that the rule "has computer" is executed before ksession.fireAllRules() is called and rule "init" is called after. This causes the variable not to be set.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as a fact is inserted, the Engine is free to evaluate, as it seems fit, conditional elements and constraints where this fact participate. Side effects being caused by methods evaluated during this procedure appear in some random order, controlled by nothing but the Engine's whim. This happens even before the Engine is fully unleashed by a call to fireAllRules or similar. Only then right hand side executions take place, the order of which may be influenced by rule attributes such as salience.

Setting globals should be done by the application launching the Drools machinery.

Comment: I understand. The thing is that we want to have a generic engine without special setup but with client-specific rules. So all client-specific initialization should be inside the rule files. I did find this way of using a "init" rule with only a then part on multiple sites, so it seems to be common practice somehow. I also found out that if I call fireAllrules BEFORE inserting the facts, then inserting the facts and then calling fireAllrules again that things seem to resolve as I want. But is it wise to do this? Thanks

Comment: I've always argued that DRL should have the equivalent of a constant definition, even if it's only a kind of macro feature. If you can make do with a preliminary fireAllRules to complete the globals: that's a fine workaround, and I don't see what should go wrong - provided none of your rules trigger due to the absence of facts in a damaging way.